# How to get rid of Thumbs.db file in Windows NTFS file system?

Tags: java, file-io

My web based java application storing files in Local Drive(E.g: `D:/AppData`). It's scanning a folder for files(`String[] nameOfFiles = dirName.list();`) and displays all the files in the folder. The `Thumbs.db` also coming with them. How to omit that file? For now, i am deleting it before scanning the folder.

Is there any other way in java to skip that file from scanning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that dirName is a File object then File.list() has an [overloaded member](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29) that takes a [FilenameFilter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) object which can be used to filter the list of files returned.